# How to properly extract orientation info of the image using Tesseract 3.04?

Tags: orientation, ocr, tesseract

I have Tesseract 3.04 static build and am trying to extract orientation info using the code provided in [official samples](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample):

```
 const char* inputfile = "/usr/src/tesseract/testing/eurotext.tif";
  tesseract::Orientation orientation;
  tesseract::WritingDirection direction;
  tesseract::TextlineOrder order;
  float deskew_angle;

  PIX *image = pixRead(inputfile);
  tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
  api->Init("/usr/src/tesseract/", "eng");
  api->SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_AUTO_OSD);
  api->SetImage(image);
  api->Recognize(0);

  tesseract::PageIterator* it =  api->AnalyseLayout();
  it->Orientation(&orientation, &direction, &order, &deskew_angle);
  printf("Orientation: %d;\nWritingDirection: %d\nTextlineOrder: %d\n" \
         "Deskew angle: %.4f\n",
         orientation, direction, order, deskew_angle);
```

My application crashes on extraction on the following line:

```
it->Orientation(&orientation, &direction, &order, &deskew_angle);
```

What is going wrong in this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are interesting in orientation info you can use [leptonica](https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica.git) instead. IMO it should be faster. See [example](https://github.com/zdenop/QT-Leptonica/blob/master/src/mainwindow.cpp#L474)

Answer (score 0):

I found orientation in tesserect by below code and it returns 0,1(=90),2(=180),3(=270) orientated sides

```
#include <osdetect.h>
#include <baseapi.h>
#include <allheaders.h>
int main()
{
    TessBaseAPI *tessBaseAPI = new TessBaseAPI();
    tessBaseAPI ->Init("/tessdataPath/", "eng")) 
    Pix *image = pixRead(imagePath);
    tessBaseAPI->SetImage(image);
    //orientation
    OSResults os_results;
    tessBaseAPI->DetectOS(&os_results);
    int orientationType=os_results.best_result.orientation_id
    pixDestroy(&image);
    return 0;
}
```